# Use of Support Library RenderScript APIs is not currently supported with Android Studio?

Tags: android, renderscript

in the developer.android.com :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis

> Note: Use of Support Library RenderScript APIs is not currently supported with Android Studio or Gradle-based builds.

this means that no any way to use this in android studio ?

my build tools 20.0.0

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658145/how-to-use-the-renderscript-support-library-with-gradle

Comment: i see this but this is no my answer :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a way to use this in Android Studio, that line in the docs is out of date and is supposed to be removed sometime. however, I don't know what it is off the top of my head! I'll take a look and see if there's a sample somewhere.