# how to use renderscriptSupportModeEnabled?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, renderscript

I'm trying to import this [library](https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur), but it is missing the ScriptC_blur class, so I did some research and found out that I had to use the renderscriptSupportModeEnabled option to import that, but it is not working at all, I can't import that class what am I missing here?

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core-slh:3.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the Renderscript Support Library with Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658145/how-to-use-the-renderscript-support-library-with-gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the lib because it might be doubled