# error while importing stackblue into Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, renderscript

I'm trying to import and add [android stackblur](https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur) into a android studio project, but it is missing the ScriptC_blur class.

I also added the following values to build.gradle for android gradle plugin v0.14.1. However, it doesn't resolve the issue

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        compile files('libs/renderscript-v8.jar')
        ...
    }
}
```

I also followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658145/how-to-use-the-renderscript-support-library-with-gradle), but I had no luck to get it to work. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated