# Set-up RenderScript in Android Studio

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm desperately trying to set-up RenderScript in Android Studio. According to this manual http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#ide-setup I have set the highest available renderscriptTargetApi 22 and        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true. I use buildToolsVersion "22.0.1". With this I am able to use the ScriptIntrinsic functions - but didn't achieve to compile an self written RenderScript (tried 20h+ now...). I always get the same problem with the R-File (red) - at the latest when I try to rebuild the Project. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Select "File/New/New Project..."
3. Press Next
4. Select "Phone and Tablet" and Minimum SDK: 4.4.
5. Press Next.
6. Select "Blank Activity".
7. Press Next.
8. Press Finish.
9. Right-click at the top of hierarchy tree on the left ("app").
10. Select "New/Folder/RenderScript folder".
11. Press Finish.
12. Copy a working renderscript file to newly created "rs" folder.
13. Double-click on "Gradle Scripts/build.gradle (Module: app).
14. Insert

    ```
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    ```

at the end of defaultConfig section.

15. Press Ctrl-F9 to build your project.

Comment: In step "12." I used the RS script from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757109/histogram-matching-in-renderscript/31765342#31765342

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug related to `renderscriptTargetApi 21+`. This has now been fixed in gradle-plugin 2.1.0 and Build-Tools 23.0.3.
Use the code below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    ...
}
```

The documentation for IDE setup has also been corrected: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#ide-setup