# Activity with blur image

Tags: android, android-activity, background-image, blur

I have `main activity` with background image and with some `buttons,editext and textviews`.
Now when I `launch` this `activity` I should have the `background image` with **`blur effect`** and all the controls visible.

I have done this way but result with no effect

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

As it is already deprectaed. Can anyone suggest me the best way to do this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795483/create-blurry-transparent-background-effect

Comment: @MunimJi-Thats what I'm actually trying to use.Can you say me how to use it for my activity ?

Comment: @coder For API>=14 you have to blur the bitmap programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these implementations for one that suits you the most:

- [Fast Bitmap Blur For Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk/10028267#10028267)
- [Advanced blurring techniques](http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/)
- [Blur effect for Android design](http://nicolaspomepuy.fr/blur-effect-for-android-design/)