# get background transparency effect like in spotify

Tags: android, layout, transparency

I want to set a background to my music player with a transparency effect like in spotify. I tried using `android:alpha="1"` to my imageview but could not get the desired effect. What i want is something like this

[image]

Here the image background is transparency version of the same image. That way a matching theme can be obtained.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add transparency with alpha property, but for adding blur background effect you should check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21052060/3110234). It worked for me and its a great solution.

Comment: i referred the link you've given.but could not understand how to do it.can you explain?

Comment: Please post your code, so that I can see your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use color code #FFFFFFFF as background color for transparency. First 2 hex digits are for transparency level. Use anything between 00 to FF for setting the desired transparency.

Comment: i want the blur effect,not transparency