# Blurred background for overlapping layout

Tags: android, layout, blur

I have an activity with its own content and I got a menu on the top which you can drag down. Currently this menu has a black, transparent background, but I want it to be blurred.

Since the content under this menu is dynamic (list of items) I solved the problem by taking a screenshot of the area beneath and blurring it, so that when the menu is dragged down I can set the screenshot as a background.

You can open/close the menu a lot and sometimes taking screenshots makes the memory of the phone colapse. It lags a lot, because it has to take a snapshot of the content before the menu is displayed every time.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Is there some way to have a blur-layout that blurs whatever is beneath it?

Is there a way to acomplish this in a design matter like having an image with whites/blacks with texture to try to blurry it out?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795483/create-blurry-transparent-background-effect

Comment: As i said in that question in the selected answer they take a snapshot of the area too to make the bitmap that will be blurred out. I want to try to avoid this if its posible