# How to Create Blur Design in android

Tags: android, uiblureffect

I want design xml in android like to image. Please. Help me!

[image: desired image]

Comment: Please google how to do it not post in stack

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795483/create-blurry-transparent-background-effect) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method:

```
public Bitmap fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap, float scale, int radius) {

    int width = Math.round(sentBitmap.getWidth() * scale);
    int height = Math.round(sentBitmap.getHeight() * scale);
    sentBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sentBitmap, width, height, false);

    Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

    if (radius < 1) {
        return (null);
    }

    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    int[] pix = new int[w * h];
    Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
    bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    int wm = w - 1;
    int hm = h - 1;
    int wh = w * h;
    int div = radius + radius + 1;

    int r[] = new int[wh];
    int g[] = new int[wh];
    int b[] = new int[wh];
    int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
    int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

    int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
    divsum *= divsum;
    int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
    for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
        dv[i] = (i / divsum);
    }

    yw = yi = 0;

    int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
    int stackpointer;
    int stackstart;
    int[] sir;
    int rbs;
    int r1 = radius + 1;
    int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
    int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

    for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
            sir = stack[i + radius];
            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
            rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
            rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
            gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
            bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
            if (i > 0) {
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
            }
        }
        stackpointer = radius;

        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

            r[yi] = dv[rsum];
            g[yi] = dv[gsum];
            b[yi] = dv[bsum];

            rsum -= routsum;
            gsum -= goutsum;
            bsum -= boutsum;

            stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
            sir = stack[stackstart % div];

            routsum -= sir[0];
            goutsum -= sir[1];
            boutsum -= sir[2];

            if (y == 0) {
                vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
            }
            p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

            rinsum += sir[0];
            ginsum += sir[1];
            binsum += sir[2];

            rsum += rinsum;
            gsum += ginsum;
            bsum += binsum;

            stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
            sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

            routsum += sir[0];
            goutsum += sir[1];
            boutsum += sir[2];

            rinsum -= sir[0];
            ginsum -= sir[1];
            binsum -= sir[2];

            yi++;
        }
        yw += w;
    }
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
        yp = -radius * w;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

            sir = stack[i + radius];

            sir[0] = r[yi];
            sir[1] = g[yi];
            sir[2] = b[yi];

            rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

            rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
            gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
            bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

            if (i > 0) {
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
            }

            if (i < hm) {
                yp += w;
            }
        }
        yi = x;
        stackpointer = radius;
        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
            pix[yi] = ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] ) | ( dv[rsum] << 16 ) | ( dv[gsum] << 8 ) | dv[bsum];

            rsum -= routsum;
            gsum -= goutsum;
            bsum -= boutsum;

            stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
            sir = stack[stackstart % div];

            routsum -= sir[0];
            goutsum -= sir[1];
            boutsum -= sir[2];

            if (x == 0) {
                vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
            }
            p = x + vmin[y];

            sir[0] = r[p];
            sir[1] = g[p];
            sir[2] = b[p];

            rinsum += sir[0];
            ginsum += sir[1];
            binsum += sir[2];

            rsum += rinsum;
            gsum += ginsum;
            bsum += binsum;

            stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
            sir = stack[stackpointer];

            routsum += sir[0];
            goutsum += sir[1];
            boutsum += sir[2];

            rinsum -= sir[0];
            ginsum -= sir[1];
            binsum -= sir[2];

            yi += w;
        }
    }

    Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
    bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    return (bitmap);
}
```

Example:

```
 Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pp);
 Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
 Bitmap bitmap = fastblur(myLogo, 0.9f, (int) 7.5f);
```

Try this :

```
 ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.car1);
    Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = fastblur(myLogo, 0.9f, (int) 7.5f);
    BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
    //navHeader.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    iv.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.car1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have shown in example. Take drawable of your resource then save it in bitmap and then pass bitmap in fastblur(), output bitmap is blurred now

Comment: I will Try it. Thanks you

Comment: let me know if it works for you or not

Comment: 1. It work. But. It not Blur full view :(
2. When I click the View.  I want it back to normal ?
Please. Help me!

Comment: set Onclick method for your imageview. Inside onclick set original image for imageview instead of blurred bitmap.

Comment: Why Image not full Blur :(. Help me!

Comment: what you mean by full blur?

Comment: Yes. I want Image full blur. But your code. It not full blur :(

Comment: In Onclick. I use. imageView.setBackgroundResoure(R.drawable.image_1); Not working.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Onclick:      mImage3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample_pic3);

Comment: OnCreat:  Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_pic3);
        Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = fastblur(myLogo, 0.9f, (int) 7.5f);
        mImage3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: This is my code ? :(

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: i will try it. thanks

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: glad it helped...also upvote my answer..:)

Comment: Why? When Onclick. Image Bitmap not hide. Please. Help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the alpha value (0-1) for the view as below:

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

This might be helpful as it is used to set opacity to the view.

Comment: I don't think so its set image as blur..!!

Comment: You can also use Renderscript API's in Support Library. Below link would be of useful to you.                                                      http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-create-bitmap-blur-effect-in-android-using-renderscript

Comment: My image as Blur. When Onclick to item. It will not Blur.

Comment: android:alpha="0.5". It blur. But when I Click item. how it is back to normal ?

Comment: On clicking the view you can remove the opacity from the view. android:alpha="0" which makes the view fully transparent

Comment: On Clicking the View. It transper. Image not show.  I want it back to normal ?. Please. Help me!